# Overnightjs how to enable cors

Tags: node.js, cors

I'm using [overnightjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@overnightjs/core) to implement Nodejs application. However, I cannot enable CORS by this code, it seems not work

```
class AppServer extends Server {
    private readonly SERVER_STARTED = 'Example server started on port: ';
    private db;

    constructor() {
        super(true);
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
        this.db = db;
        this.setupControllers();

        this.app.use(function(req, res, next) {
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
            next();
        });
    }
}
```

I have also tried with cors library but it also does not

`this.app.use(cors());`

Anyone can help me,

Thank a lots

Comment: can you share `setupControllers` code?

Comment: Hi @SandeepPatel

This is setup code

``` PHP
    private setupControllers(): void {
        const ctlrInstances = [];
        for (const name in controllers) {
            if (controllers.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                const controller = (controllers as any)[name];
                ctlrInstances.push(new controller());
            }
        }
        super.addControllers(ctlrInstances);
    }
```

Do you need anything else ?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot format the code by using code fencesm it does not work

Comment: Hi @SandeepPatel
I have found the solution and replied my post, thank for you supporing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. we should put **cors** plugin before class name of controller as middleware like this. it should work

```
import { ClassMiddleware, Controller, Get } from '@overnightjs/core';
import * as cors from 'cors';

@Controller('/')
@ClassMiddleware([cors()])
class HomeController {
}
```